# Testing @preAuthorize(custom_implementation) with MockMvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I added `@preAuthorize("@securityService.hasPermission()")` on top of my controller method and created related bean with given method-

```
  @Configuration
   public class SecurityConfig {
   @Bean
   public PreAuthorizationSecurityService securityService() {
      return new PreAuthorizationSecurityService();
   }
  }
```

Now, I'm using MockMvc for testing my controller. When I add `SecurityConfig.class` to `ContextConfiguration` of the test class,controller method checks for permission. But, I want to mock `PreAuthorizationSecurityService` in a way that my class doesn't have to import `SecurityConfig.class` for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to declare a mock of your service instead of importing the entire `SecurityConfig`, you can easily do so by declaring this in your test config :

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfig {
    @Bean
    public PreAuthorizationSecurityService mockedSecurityService() {
        //providing you use Mockito for mocking purpose
        return mock(PreAuthorizationSecurityService.class);
    }
}
```

And then set your mock to return true when needed. You can also provide your own mocked implementation that always return true.

---

That said, this is not the usual way to use Spring Security. And you should consider refactoring your app to use the standard role-based system, it will save you some trouble.

I don't know what your `PreAuthorizationSecurityService` looks like and if this can apply in your situation but in most cases, it should and that's what you should aim for.

With this standard role based approach, Spring Security Test (v4+ I think) easily allows you to mock connected user with given roles with annotation like [`@WithMockUser`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/test-method.html#test-method-withmockuser).